# Cannot start mysql by 'su mysql'

Tags: mysql

OS - RHEL 5.5
I have root access to the server. I have also created a user 'mysql' on the seerver.
The mysql db was preinstalled for us and user mysql was created as a root user of the db.

Here is what happens
If I login to the machine with user mysql, I can access the mysql shell. But when I log in as root, I cannot access the mysql shell even when I do 'su mysql'

Question - What is the reason behind this behavior? Isn't logging in with 'mysql' and changing to user 'mysql' the same things?

Comment: You do mean `sudo mysql` right?

Comment: do want to access mysql database through root user?

Comment: was the command "su mysql" successful (-> 'whoami')? If not, the shell for the user mysql might have been (by default) defined as '/bin/false' instead of e.g. '/bin/bash'.

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, you have a mysql user without a password.

Try this

```
mysql -u mysql
```

Or

```
su - mysql
mysql
```

The "-" on su makes it a proper login shell, so that all environment variables (and everything else) is set up the same way as logging in directly as that user.